# How to run a local powershell script into remote machine via ansible?

Tags: powershell, ansible

I am converting my linux ansible scripts into windows. There is a module named "script" is available which is running local script to remote target machine.
But there is no equvalent win_script module is present. 
When i used win_shell module it was expecting the file to be in remote machine.

```
- name: Create a filesystem and perform IO operation using powershell script
  win_shell: "{{pshfile}} {{disc_ip}} {{storage_array_vol}} {{file1}}"
```

Is there any way to run local powershell script into remote machine via ansible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the script first to the target node, then execute it.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_copy_module.html